# Do weights of a Lie Algebra include 0 eigenvalue but roots do not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In our groups lecture notes we define weights by:

$$\omega: H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \ \ \ r(H)v = \omega(H)v$$
$$V = \oplus_\omega V_\omega$$

whereas we define roots (in the adjoint representation) by:

$$\alpha: \mathcal{H}  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \ \ \ ad_H(E_\alpha) = \alpha(H)E_\alpha$$
$$\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{H} \oplus_\alpha \mathcal{L}_\alpha$$

This seems like one would not call the $\alpha=0$ case a 'root' but one *would* call the $\omega=0$ case a 'weight'. Is this true? Is this a conventional definition?

Comment: Is this just a definition thing? Or am I missing an insight?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha\neq 0$ is a definition in the context of the root space decomposition, where $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{L}_0$ already is the Cartan subalgebra with $\alpha=0$. For weights we only require $V_{\omega}\neq 0$.